# Why isn't scrollTo scrolling to my anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

[...]

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getusto(anchorid) {
$(anchorid).scrollTo();
} 

</script>

[...]

</head>
<body>

[...]

<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="getusto('welcome');">Welcome</a><br> 
<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="getusto('guidelines');">Guidelines</a> 

[...]

<a name="welcome" id="welcome"></a> blah balhb albha 

[...]

<a name="guidelines" id="guidelines"></a> blah blahb alhb

[...]

</body>
</html>
```

why does clicking the welcome/guidelines links not scroll to the anchors?

i am trying to link to the ids specifically, due to using jquery-bbq which makes it (as far as i can tell) so i CAN'T use hashes/anchors normally.

they are making me use more characters to explain the code. how about we play one frame pac-man:

```
("< . . . . o . . . . 
                    . 
                    .
                    .
                    .
             [Post Your Answer]
```

Comment: Why not just `<a href="#welcome">Welcom</a>`?

Comment: hey Rob - see latest addition. it's a quirk/tradeoff of jquery-bbq, apparently, hashes are used for one thing, so not this other - i.e.  i can't use anchors, because jquery-bbq uses them for something else. so, i have to find a workaround - am trying `scrollTo()` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the browser is performing the `Element.scrollTo` function and then following the link... which takes you to the top of the page (since the `href` is `#`).

Why not try one of these two things and see what happens:

Try `return false;` from the `onclick`: ([see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GWLmy/1/))

```
<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="getusto('welcome'); return false;">Welcome</a>
<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="getusto('guidelines'); return false;">Guidelines</a>
```

Or make `getusto` return `false`: ([see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mVusg/1/))

```
function getusto(anchorid) {
  $(anchorid).scrollTo();
  return false;
}
```

...and return its value from the `onclick`:

```
<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="return getusto('welcome');">Welcome</a>
<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="return getusto('guidelines');">Guidelines</a>
```

Doing either of the two suggestions should allow the `Element.scrollTo` to take effect without following the original destination of the links.

Comment: `<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="getusto('welcome'); return false;">Welcome</a><br> 
<a class="menu_links" href="#" onclick="getusto('guidelines'); return false;">Guidelines</a>` did not work. i'll try the other method.

Comment: didn't work. if it helps i used Egg Thrower to throw some eggs at the page =P

Comment: I created a fiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/GWLmy/1/. If you're still having problems I'm afraid you'll have to provide more information.

Comment: PAH - you win. i didn't know anchor tags (even tho we're not using the `name` part of the anchor, for anyone reading) had to be AROUND something. it sort of jittered when i tested yours (you were right), but it didn't 'scroll' because i didn't have the anchors AROUND the text. THANKS MAN! Very helpful =D 

- joe

Comment: I'm glad it helped. One thing that's important to remember too is that there needs to be enough content BELOW the target element to scroll that element to the top. If the whole page fits on one screen you won't be able to scroll far enough down to make a difference and it may appear that your links aren't doing anything.

Comment: It's really answer that needed, I will delete mine ))

Comment: hey, Zack & mesiesta, if you're still up i ran into another problem immediately, any help would be cool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907588/why-does-including-prototype-js-break-the-functioning-of-jquery-bbq