# prototypejs altering jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

On my page here: `redacted`

I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of null`, and the element that's supposed to drop down just stays covering the top of the page (the big white image)

When I delete prototype.js the header image drops down from the top as it's supposed to. My working knowledge of javascript is very basic so I can't see what the issue is.

What would be the easiest solution to this problem, assuming I need both js files?

Thanks!

Edited: redacted URL - the solution used was to add : `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` at the top of the jQuery scripts and replace all instances of $ with $j. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please post relevant code here. Many people wont follow links to find what you're talking about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does including prototype.js break the functioning of jquery bbq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907588/why-does-including-prototype-js-break-the-functioning-of-jquery-bbq)

Comment: noted - will keep in mind in the future. adding the parts i think are relevant to the post. as i'm not sure what the problem is, it's a little tricky to figure out which parts of the code people should be looking at. :)

Comment: I did search before posting, I missed that post @WereWolf-TheAlpha. 

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before your `.ready()` function, write `jQuery.noConflict();`

read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: thank you... i did  search for something similar but missed that post.